# All entities from mysql not being indexed in elasticsearch when using jdbc RIVER

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch

I have a MySQL db with a table that has `191000` entities. But when indexing in elasticsearch using `JDBC river`, only `21,274` entities are being indexed.How do I troubleshoot this?

This is my JDBC configuration :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/hello/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tdb",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from test"
    }
}'
```

Where `tdb` is my database and `test` is the table having 191000 entities.

Comment: Welcome on SO! You should probably share a few more information, such as the configuration of your JDBC river, at the very least. As much info as you think can help us help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As such, I doubt your question can be answered, you don't give enough details. Maybe you could describe how you indexed the input data base ? (edit question, not in comments). Also check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks a lot..Sorry for the inconvenience.Will look into it and get back,Sir.

Comment: Take a look at the answer that I gave here, it might help !

Comment: where?I am sorry.I am an amateur yet in using SO

Comment: hey!reas your answer.I have to change the query_timeout .i tried methods,but i am not able to change is successfully.How do i go about?